# In macOS mail, is it possible to automatically mark archived messages as read?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, automation

I am aware that the macOS mail app has "rules", but I cannot seem to find an option that targets messages in a specific mailbox (except for the spam box).

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93222

Comment: @JBallin my question is specifically about the native macOS mailing app, I do not use Gmail. Thanks for the recommendation though.

Comment: I realize you want an automation, but note that you should be able mark all archived mail as read on demand by right clicking the folder.

Comment: FYI, rules don't target specific folders because they only run automatically when processing incoming mail. They can move messages into folders, but they don't process messages that are already in folders.

Answer (score -1):

Part of this can be done with AppleScript :

```
on run
   tell application "Mail"
      set read status of every message of mailbox "Archive" of account "AccountName" to true
   end tell
end run
```

Replace 'Archive' by your archive mailbox name (where your archived emails are automatically put) and 'AccountName' by the name of your Mail account (e.g. "John").

This AppleScript will check through your archive mailbox for unread emails and mark them as read.

You can just run it each time you want or use Automator to have it run whenever you want or to automate it.

Comment: To make this fully automatic, OP would need to use [FastScripts](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) or [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to intercept the keystroke for archive (and the OP couldn't use gestures - only key shortcut) to archive the mail(s).  Or make a better AppleScript to get selected mail message(s), mark them read, then archive them. This too would need to be defined as a key stroke or inserted in to a menu bar / activation like [LaunchBar](https://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) might do.